# SSAS cube - Finding count of days overdue per order

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I'm trying to add a new measure to my OLAP cube, in SSAS.

The fact table is at the order detail level, so each row in the fact table represents an order and a product, like:

[image: Order details]
I'd like to add a measure that indicates the maximum number of days overdue per order number. So that measure should say:

OrderNo 1 -> 5 days overdue

OrderNo 2 -> 1 day overdue

OrderNo 3 -> 0 days overdue

I have tried using the MAX operator, with no success.

By the way, this is a multidimensional SSAS schema. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are we to assume this is SSAS multidimensional and you are trying to create a calculated measure? Or are you trying to make this happen in the DSV before it gets to the cube? What version of SQL Server you are using might also be helpful.

Comment: It's a multidimensional database on SSAS 2008. Thanks !!

Comment: How did you try to "use the MAX operator"? Is `OrderNo` available in the cube as an attribute?

Comment: Yes, OrderNo is an attribute of the Fact table (it's a degenerate dimension).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a measure "max days overdue" or how ever you want to call it in the cube designer, tab "cube structure". In the properties of the measure, use "Max" as the aggregate function. That's it.

Comment: Thanks, you are totally right. I was a bit confused over this, but a simple MAX aggregate does the job. I thought I had to had a "MAX over column".